# Deploying artifacts from nested projects using Artifactory Jenkins plugin

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory

I'm working on a project that uses Maven 3.0.4 .

A sample project structure

```
parent Project (packaging=pom, modules=model, services)
  model Project (packaging=pom, modules=hr-model, gl-model)
    hr-model Project (packaging=jar)
    gl-model Project (packaging=jar)
  services Project (packging=pom, modules=hr-services, gl-services)
    hr-services Project (packaging=jar)
    gl-services Project (packaging=jar)
```

We are using artifactory as our repository management tool and Jenkins as our CI build server. The artifactory/Jenkins plugin has also been installed.

If I set up a project in Jenkins as a Maven 2/3 project for hr-model and add a post build step to deploy to artifactory then a jar artifact gets deployed to artifactory.

Doing so for the model project results in two jar artifacts (hr-model.jar and gl-model.jar) being deployed to artifactory.

Doing so for the parent project results in NO artifacts being deployed to artifactory.

Is there any way to get the artifactory jenkins plugin to deploy hr-model.jar, gl-model.jar, hr-services.jar and gl-services.jar?

Thanks,

Peter.

Comment: Isn't a module missing in the parent `parent Project (packaging=pom, modules=model)`, cause i would expect having the following: `parent Project (packaging=pom, modules=model, services)`?

Comment: Yes, have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, Artifactory intercept what your build tool deploy in the local repository (.m2), and then deploying it into Artifactory.

You should check what maven deploy in the local repository.

Comment: I checked this and the build tool _is_ deploying artifacts to the local repository it only seems to have an issue with nested projects i.e. pom (with modules) > pom (with modules) > jar/war etc.